# How do you do a post request with xml?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reproduce an post request but the examples of sending a post request include parameters and the example I'm trying to reporduce doesn't show parameters, just xml

Comment: Show what YOU have tried. Maybe we can help

Comment: Is this with the `requests` module? With `urllib2`, `urllib.request`, what? Do you mean you want to POST an XML document somewhere? That's just a post body, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of sending a POST request with XML data.

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/xml'}
data = '<hello>world</hello>'

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', headers=headers, data=data)
assert r.ok
```